# Welding Aluminum to Medium Carbon Steel

Tags: welding

I have a table flat surface made from aluminum, and the table legs are made from medium carbon steel. What are 3 welding processes that could be used to weld the legs to the flat surface.

Comment: What are the melting points of the two metals?

Comment: My question would be from what class and/or homework does this originate?

Comment: I think a Sonic Screwdriver (season 7 and later) has this capability.

Comment: Do you mean “Welding” or “Joining”? They are non synonymous

Comment: This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 2):

Can't be done . Soldering and brazing physical properties would be poor. I think there is one possibility , which you can not afford, explosion bonding . A piece of aluminum is forced against steel by explosive force. Even that would be a challenge because of the very large differences in properties.  Then aluminum would be welded to the aluminum side and steel welded to the steel side ; still I see a lot of problems. Think epoxy or bolts.

Comment: You can buy the stuff pre-explosive-bonded and weld the al to the al and steel to steel. [triclad](http://www.empo.com.tr/aluminium-bars/triclad.html?lang=en). This is how thousands of boats are built with steel hulls and aluminum superstructures each year

Comment: See here for an illustration of how Triclad is implemented: http://www.maritimeservicesdirectory.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Merrem-beeld.jpg There is no reason this theory couldn't be used to join table legs to a table top

Comment: It's been about 40 yr since I looked at explosion bonding; I guess there have been developments. Apparently the "triclad" bar is sawn from a plate to make the smaller sections. Interesting that the figure faintly shows the classic ripples at the bond interfaces.